# Jira JQL - Show all issues by Epic assignee

Tags: filter, jira, jql, epic

I am using a vanilla version of Jira (I can't install any add-ons - it's company wide).

I'm trying to filter to show all issues for a given team. The ideal way to do this IMO is to assign their team leader to their epics and have Jira filter to show all the issues within that set of epics.

So far, I've hit a brick wall. I can easily setup a filter to return the epic for a given user - or return all tickets assigned to a user generally. However, I cannot seem to return all tasks related to all epics of which the specified user is the assignee.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Does it have Script Runner plugin installed by any chance? Then something like this would work: issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("assignee = user", "is Epic of")

Comment: I wish it did. It's literally the out-of-the-box version, with no add-ons. The dept that looks after it won't install anything else.

Comment: I think it's not possible with standard JQL. Similiar question: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/Filter-based-on-filtered-epics-quot-epic-link-quot-in/qaq-p/451450